# Tabs Coming above Action bar

Tags: java, android

> I Am trying to create an actionbar with the custom centralised text, I tried with this following code but the Tab View will appear above the action bar which customized text, here is my code and screen shot of image[image: Screen shot of view]:

```
    actionBar = getActionBar();

    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);

    View mCustomView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.actionbar_custom, null);

    TextView mTitleTextView = (TextView) mCustomView.findViewById(R.id.text);
    mTitleTextView.setText("Logs");

    ActionBar.LayoutParams layoutParams = new  ActionBar.LayoutParams(ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL|Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;

    getActionBar().setCustomView(mCustomView, layoutParams);

    actionBar.setCustomView(mCustomView);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);

    adapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
```